# Can an 'if' statement have more than one resulting 'then'?

Tags: java, if-statement

I do apologize if this question is too simple but I have tried Google and I cannot find a concrete answer (mostly because I do not know how to word my question).

I am just wondering if an if statement in Java can have more than one 'then' i.e.

```
public class test {

     if (condition) {
      then...;
      then 2...?;
     }
}
```

For example, the first condition is true. The first then occurs, which say throws an exception. Could I add on another then after that which would also occur after the exception is thrown?

Thanks for looking

EDIT: I understand my question is a bit ambiguous. I guess what I'm trying to say is something like this:

```
public class test {

  public String checkAnswer(String answer) throws Exception {
     if (!a == b) {
      throw new Exception;
      this.ans = this.ans + a;
     }
     else {
        return "You are wrong."
}
```

Is that second line (this.ans ...) allowed to be there? As in would both throw new Exception and that line both occur if the condition was not met?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to mix if-else and try-catch, not "looking for an if with more than one resulting then"

Comment: There is no `then` in Java.  But if you're asking if there can be more than one statement in the block following an `if`, then yes.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes I understand there is no then, the thens I placed were intended to be variables for expressions that should occur if the condition is true.

Comment: This is an example of a question in which is the answer is to try it.

Comment: @cursayer can you provide more pseudo-code, like an example of what you are trying to do ... then an alternative solution will be easier to provide. You could also use a second (nested) `if`, or possibly a `switch` statement, instead of the any `if`s.

Comment: `then` and `then 2` just seem like two lines (one after the other)....

Comment: @JoeBoyle I am trying it but I keep getting an error and I'm worried that what I'm doing is causing it.

Comment: @cursayer And that error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can nest if blocks, if that is what you're asking. This is legal Java:

```
if (foo) {
  if (bar) {
    System.out.println("both foo and bar are true");
  } else {
    System.out.println("foo is true, but bar is false");
  }
} else {
  if (bar) {
    System.out.println("foo is false, but bar is true");
  } else {
    System.out.println("both foo and bar are false");
  }
}
```

But this can also be written in a non-nested fashion:

```
if (foo && bar) {
  System.out.println("both foo and bar are true");
} else if (foo && !bar) {
    System.out.println("foo is true, but bar is false");
} else if (!foo && bar) {
    System.out.println("foo is false, but bar is true");
} else {
    System.out.println("foo and bar are both false");
}
```

---

**Edit**
Regarding your new code:

```
public class test {

  public String checkAnswer(String answer) throws Exception {
     if (!a == b) {
      throw new Exception;
      this.ans = this.ans + a;
     }
     else {
        return "You are wrong."
}
```

First of all, it won't compile, and you should really strive to only post code that either compiles or that if your problem is a compilation issue, then is your best effort to get it to compile, and then you show your compilation errors.

Assuming you add parenthesis to `new Exception();` your compiler should still show a problem since the code below the thrown exception is unreachable.

Instead, you will want the line under the throw exception to be **above** it. You will also want to correct your inequality statement:

```
     if (a != b) {  // ** note the different equality test
       this.ans = this.ans + a;
       throw new AnswerWrongException("some string here");
     }
```

You have an amazing laboratory available to you -- your Java compiler and JVM, and you should test this stuff out and see what it tells you, as it can give you a correct and clear answer before any of us can.

Comment: Not exactly, what I mean to ask is could I do this: (taken from your first example)

    if (foo) {
      if (bar) {
        System.out.println("both foo and bar are true");
        System.out.println("foo is true, but bar is false");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("foo is false");
    }

Comment: @cursayer: but if your goal is to call multiple methods within an if block, then yes, this is possible. That is why we have *code blocks* in Java. Please edit and clarify your question if at all possible.

Comment: @cursayer: see edit to answer. Note that you're posting sort-of kind-of Java code. Please try not to do this as it can make things more confusing than they really are.

Comment: I apologize. I wasn't really going for compilability but more for just asking if I can have those two expressions after the if.

Comment: @cursayer: Try it. Test it. Find out. That's what your compiler is for.

Comment: You are missing a brackets in "throw new AnswerWrongException("some string here";", there should be a brackets after "here" ;) (Can't edit it because there need to change at least 6 characters..)

Answer (score 1):

First, no there are no multi-then(s) whatever that is. Given this question though,

> For example, the first condition is true. The first then occurs, which say throws an exception. Could I add on another then after that which would also occur after the exception is thrown?

You really are asking for a `finally` block, so use one.

```
try {
  if (condition) {
    System.out.println("condition is true");
  } else {
    System.out.println("condition is false");
  }
} finally {
  System.out.println("This always prints");
}
```

**Edit**

> if (a + b == c) is true, can I then put two different actions in the proceeding block (a = a + b) and (b = b + c)

Yes. And you can use `+=` since you want to assign the result of the arithmetic to the first term -

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
if (a + b == c) {
  a += b;
  b += c;
}
System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d%n", a, b, c);
```

Comment: Sorry I guess my question was worded poorly. What I mean to say is that for example: the if condition is true, could I then execute two separate actions after that? Say: if (a + b == c) is true, can I then put two different actions in the proceeding block (a = a + b) and (b = b + c)

Answer (score 0):

No, an if statement can only have one then. If blah then blah. I'm not 100% positive, thought it probably also depends on the coding language.
Though in java, no.

Answer (score 0):

Everything within the if-block gets executed:

```
public class test {

    if (condition) {
        methodA();
        methodB();
    }
}
```

Here, because both methods are in between the curly brackets (`{}`), both `methodA()` and `methodB()` get executed.

Introducing exception handling changes the answer depending on how you write the exception. If you write it so that it breaks out of the current code block at `methodA()`, then `methodB()` will not be executed. Of course, you would have to be purposely writing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `if` statements.
What you want is a `try-catch` block:

```
 if (condition) {
     try {
         // some code that may throw exceptions
     } catch (SomeException e) {
         //
     }
     // some more code, which can also be in anoth try-catch
 }
```